# How to set a function name in a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I recently started to play around with `React` and am facing an issue in the code below. Here is my component, the question will follow:

```
class CustomButton extends Component {
    render() { 
        const {number,parent} = this.props;
        return (
            <button className="button"
            onClick={() => parent.onEvent123()}>Option{number}
            </button>
        )
    }
}

export default CustomButton;
```

This component is already working. I can use it like that:

```
<CustomButton number={123} parent={this.props} />
```

And the onClick line maps to:

```
onClick={() => this.props.onEvent123()}>Option123
```

But here is what I really want:

```
<CustomButton number={789} parent={this.props} />
```

mapping to:

```
onClick={() => this.props.onEvent789()}>Option789
```

for any number (here 789) I pass.

I have tried something like:

```
return (
    <button className="button"
    onClick={() => parent.onEvent{number}()}>Option{number}
    </button>
)
```

in order to parameterize the function name, but it doesn't work. What is the way to get what I want? Of course I would not want to pass the hard coded function name.
I have the feeling there has to be a solution. But I am still too beginner in React.

Comment: parent[\`onEvent${number}\`] . Also you probably shouldn't name your prop "number", since it's a data type name

Comment: OK. Thanks for the advice. I will fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
return (
    <button className="button"
    onClick={() => parent[`onEvent${number}`]()}>Option{number}
    </button>
)
```